# Calculating distances between boundaries of polygons with Python

Tags: python, polygon, geoprocessing, open-source-gis, distance

I have two sets of shape-files which have to be worked on within a Python Script. Those two Shape Files *might* differ from each other (same thematic content, but 2 different epochs).

If there occurred a change in geometry over the years within an object I am supposed to detect it, but only if the boundary changed more than x m in at least 1 place.

I am working completely with open source libraries within my scripts.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: Witch distance, between nodes, between segments, between centroids ?

Comment: closest distance between line segments